# Url key was already generated for an item with the SKU Import File

Tags: magento2.3, php, import-products

When I import product CSV in Magento 2.3.5. I am getting the error as below1.
*Url key: '471-010-transparente' was already generated for an item with the SKU: '471_010-Transparente-40'. You need to specify the unique URL key manually in row(s): 4, 5, 6*

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

Change the url key because URL is already generated by another product so magento is refusing to accept that URL key.

URL key must me unique

Answer (score 0):

This happens  when you  try to add products in magento having duplicate names . If  the magento had  already a product with same name the url  is generated according to the  name . So  in short  DON'T DUPLICATE PRODUCT NAME if you  are not specifying product urls manually in the upload csv

There are 2 possible  solutions  .

1. change your product name in the rows 4, 5, 6 manually in the csv and you  will  be able to upload  the  product. after that you  can open the product from the admin and change it back to  whatever you  want

OR

2. Add a new column named url in the csv and specify a unique url in the csv for all product. This way there wont  be  duplicate urls  even if  product name are  same  .